# Remap the filter data in a Kendo grid for a better format

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid

How do I reformat my data in a kendo grid drop down filter? The data I'm getting back doesn't match how I would like it to be displayed for JUST the *filter*.

Example:

- inactive_user
- active
- disabled_user

And I would like this displayed in the *filter* drop down like this

- Inactive user
- Active
- Disabled User

I'm having trouble digging around in the jQuery docs, (that's the version I'm using) and configuring the filter template if there is one. Here's what I've got so far showing the "flat" version

```
filterable: {
  multi: true, 
  search: true
},
```

**edit**

I found that you can use dataSource to insert manual items, but not sure how I can replace the title still, or if this is the right track...

```
dataSource: [{
status: "inactive_user",
  },{
status: "active",
  },....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the default filter element used by the column's filter with one that embeds a DropDownList. Next, you can override the template and value template of the dropDownList to suite your needs.

NOTE : I cant remember off the top of my head if this is the exact syntax for the templates data, however, it is the basic principle.

```
filterable: {
      ...
    ui: activeFilter
      ...
}


function activeFilter(element) {
    element.kendoDropDownList({
         dataSource: ...,
         dataTextField:...,
         dataValueField:'myValue',
         valueTemplate: 'convertStatus('+#:data.myValue+')',
         template: 'convertStatus('+#:data.myValue+')'
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I got that to work as a drop down list. One more question, is it possible to turn it into a multi-select? And remove the "Show items with value that:" drop down above it? (equals, not equals, etc.)

Comment: I know there are properties that can be set to override the text values for the filter labels, however, I have not seen the option to show/not show. If you can find the wrapper for what you are after you may be able to pull  something off without out making things look wonky, I have never tried.